# random “NULL character(s) present” error in exim

Tags: linux, docker, exim, null

Sometimes we are getting **NULL character(s) present** errors on incoming mail. It looks like this:

```
2018-03-01 12:26:51.244 [22933] SMTP syntax error in "RCPT TO:" H=mail-wm0-f56.google.com [74.125.82.56]:59392 I=[185.78.30.71]:25 NULL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2018-03-01 13:07:10.371 [4718] SMTP syntax error in "RCPT TO:" H=mail-vk0-f59.google.com [209.85.213.59]:34762 I=[185.78.30.71]:25 NULL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2018-03-04 16:48:37.084 [32374] SMTP syntax error in "??EHLO 102jamz.com" H=[78.90.185.253]:50824 I=[185.78.30.71]:25 NULL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2018-03-04 17:00:30.333 [4600] SMTP syntax error in "??EHLO 1stglobal.com" H=[168.103.12.254]:43198 I=[5.101.158.68]:25 NULL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2018-03-05 11:11:42.758 [27678] SMTP syntax error in "D?TA" H=mail-pf0-f176.google.com [209.85.192.176]:42851 I=[185.78.30.71]:25 NULL character(s) present (shown as '?')
```

We have had successful transfers from hosts with these errors. The error only happens sometimes.

It has different commands (ehlo / rcpt to / data ), different hosts. At the same time there are no errors in `dmesg`, so it has no correlation with hardware error. Some TCP fails? Don't know, it looks like "we miss 1 byte in big package", is it real case?

Having 4 mail servers for incoming and 4/4 gets this error in some time.

exim 4.90.1

linux kernel 4.7.10

exim under docker enviroment. docker 1.8.3, build f4bf5c7

Comment: OK, at now i had check logs again and see difference: not google fails on EHLO and google fails on the RCPT TO and DATA

Answer (score 2):

Known bug:

https://bugs.exim.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2250

Patch being tested right now, but a workaround is to disable PIPELINING with:

pipelining_advertise_hosts =

(i.e. an empty list)